# Insert to Database from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a class `Connect` to connect to the Database. Here is the code:

```
    class Connect
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public Connect()
    {
        String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable executeSelect(String query)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }

    public void execute(String query)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

And i have `DataGridView` like this:

[image: My data]

How is the code to insert all data from that `DataGridView` to the `Database`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert entire DataTable into database at once instead of row by row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row)

Answer (score 0):

If you write your last sentence to Google you will get this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556556/insert-all-data-of-a-datagridview-to-database-at-once) at first. And your answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  need to use  loop insertion.You have to put all  data in a list.
Or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row)

because you have a  **DataTable** in your post codes.